# How to get the client IP address in Openshift?

Tags: php, openshift

I try `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and not working (return an wrong IP).
Then try

```
function get_ip_address()
{
    $ip_keys = array(
        'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
        'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED',
        'REMOTE_ADDR'
    );
    foreach ($ip_keys as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {
                // trim for safety measures
                $ip = trim($ip);
                // attempt to validate IP
                if (validate_ip($ip)) {
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : false;
}
```

But still not working.
 `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` Always return 127.6.79.1 however this is not my IP address!

Comment: "and not working (return an IP)" --- what should it return?

Comment: @zerkms Sorry return wrong IP

Comment: Say no to unindented code!!

Comment: i'm sorry but thats the best you can get.

Comment: what value you are getting for $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?

Comment: @user7282 Always return 127.6.79.1 however this is not my IP address!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran a var_dump on $_SERVER for an OpenShift Online app using the PHP-5.4 cartridge. The user IP came back as HTTP_X_CLIENT_IP and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR. For reference, REMOTE_ADDR came back with the address of my server (REMOTE_ADDR = SERVER_ADDR = OPENSHIFT_PHP_IP).